# Create categories from array of intervals

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Given a set of ranges as follow

```
dates = [[1200, 1300], [1100, 1300], [1200, 1300], [1200, 1400], [1100, 1400]]
```

I would like to extract in an efficient way all the possible intervals and then count the number of ranges available in each interval.

For that example the resulting matrix of possible intervals would be:

```
     [1100, 1200]  [1200, 1300]  [1300, 1400]
0           0          1           0
1           1          1           0
2           0          1           0
3           0          1           1
4           1          1           1
```

Then, the sum by column gives the number of ranges that are in each interval

```
[1100, 1200]    2
[1200, 1300]    5
[1300, 1400]    2
```

Comment: In the case that there is an interval say `[1100, 1150]`, do we create a new range or does your problem require using fixed interval length? In your example, you have `interval_length = 100`.

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao No it does not require a fixed interval length.
 
In the case that there is an interval say [1100, 1150], we should have the  intervals  [1100, 1150] and [1150, 1200]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach giving you the wanted `numpy` matrix `m`, with boolean values:

```
def getOverlap(a, b):
    return max(0, min(a[1], b[1]) - max(a[0], b[0]))

nodes     = sorted(np.unique(np.array(dates).flatten()))
intervals = zip(nodes[:-1], nodes[1:])
# [(1100, 1200), (1200, 1300), (1300, 1400)]

m = np.array([[bool(getOverlap(i, d)) for d in dates] for i in intervals])

m.sum(axis=1)
# array([2, 5, 2])
```

Note that if you want the 'matrix' to be a `pandas` `DataFrame`, simply do:

```
pd.DataFrame(m.transpose().astype(int), columns=intervals)

   (1100, 1200)  (1200, 1300)  (1300, 1400)
0             0             1             0
1             1             1             0
2             0             1             0
3             0             1             1
4             1             1             1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this method here. Can be more compact than this. Thats for another day!

```
c=[[1200, 1300], [1100, 1300], [1200, 1300], [1200, 1400], [1100, 1400]]
print "string values", c
uniquea={}
new=[]
for i in c:
    j=str(i)
    if j in new:
        uniquea[j]+=1
    else:
        uniquea[j]=1
        new.append(j)
```

print uniquea, new